# Convert name attribute of igraph from character to numeric

Tags: r, igraph

Given a graph with names of type string:

```
graph.toy <- make_empty_graph(n=9)
graph.toy <- add_edges(graph.toy, c(2,1,
                                  3,1,
                                  4,2,
                                  5,1,
                                  6,5,
                                  7,2,
                                  8,1,
                                  9,6))

V(graph.toy)$name <- c('d', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i')
```

Imagine we want to re-label the nodes with an integer that indicates their alphabetic order:

```
int.labels <- rank(V(graph.toy)$name)
# [1] 4 1 2 5 3 6 7 8 9
```

How can I change the `name`attribute from characters to numerics? The difficulty is that igraph preserves the first type of the attribute.

```
V(graph.toy)$name <- int.labels
# [1] "4" "1" "2" "5" "3" "6" "7" "8" "9"
```

And since it is the `name` attribute, we can't make it NULL and then re-build it, since it would lose the graph structure.

Comment: try `sort()` instead of `order()`

Comment: Actually it should be rank, thanks ! ;)